# Postfix reject client from domains without MX records

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

Machine `mail.domain.com` send email for `domain.com` through Postfix 2.11 but today reviewing `mail.log` file i noticed some Wordpress on machines `wordpress.domain.com` and  `blog.domain.com` as sending email through `mail.domain.com` where sender address is `user@wordpress.domain.com` and `user@blog.domain.com`. Obviously they configured Wordpress to authenticate and send email to `mail.domain.com`.

The issue here is `mail.domain.com` is responsible of sending email for `domain.com` but not `*.domain.com` so the latter are not DKIM signed and obviously are not valid recipient addresses as those domains are not able to recieve email so i would like to reject clients using a from domain address which is not able to receive email like `*.domain.com`.

I've been looking at the docs `http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html` but i'm unable to find a neat solution. Does anyone know how can i accomplish that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Removing warn_if_rejected solved the problem. Stupid mistake!! :D

In order to avoid from/sender address spoofing i'm trying without success the following settings:

The following policies are added to the existing ones at `smtpd_sender_restrictions` statement:

```
warn_if_reject reject_unlisted_sender,
warn_if_reject reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch
```

I also added the following table in order let Postfix know when the sender login mismatches:

```
## Optional lookup table with the SASL login names that own sender (MAIL FROM) addresses.
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_sender_login_maps.cf
```

$ cat /etc/postfix/mysql_sender_login_maps.cf

```
user=mail_user
password=mail_user_password
dbname=mail_db
hosts=127.0.0.1
query=SELECT u.email FROM `users` AS u WHERE u.email = '%s' AND u.enabled IS TRUE
```

While the previous setup seems to work fine i'm suffering a small issue which breaks it all. Right now Postfix rejects email spoofing based on the owner of the from/sender address but after passing the email to amavisd-new in order to get the content scanned, when amavisd-new injects the email back to Postfix i don't know why Postfix finally send the email. I imagine, somewhere probably in master.cf, some restrictions get overriden but i'm unable to find the bug.

Here's the mail.log https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2cb8736aa2baeef7dbd8 where to check how it is first rejected then delivered.

Here's master.cf just in case an edit is needed https://gist.github.com/sibok/7d10c8d267170f4deb43

$ postconf |grep mail_version
mail_version = 2.11.0

$ postconf -n
https://gist.github.com/sibok/b3c8208d3fae7d696e3f

I hope someone can give some bits of help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with `parent_domain_matches_subdomains` and `smtpd_sender_restrictions`. Add the following to your `main.cf`

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
#...
parent_domain_matches_subdomains =
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_blacklists
#...

#/etc/postfix/sender_blacklists
domain.com      OK
.domain.com     REJECT
```

Ref: [postfix access Readme](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html)

Comment: Clement, thanks a lot for your help but i think i need to find the way to check whether client/from address is reachable or not. I would like to avoid to manually/programatically ban all subdomains and then check that rule on sending. One solution would be to force client/from address to match the login address but i think the best shot is to only allow client/from addresses which are reachable. Do you know how can i accomplish that? Thanks again!

Comment: allowing from addresses which are only reachable. Do you mean something like `reject_unknown_sender_domain`?

Comment: No, sender_domain is going to be reachable as long as it has an A or CNAME RR but it doesn't mean servers unders MX RR accept email for those RR. I mean, foo.mydomain.com may be reachable but mydomain.com MX RR may only accept email for mydomain.com and not *.mydomain.com I would like to make sure domains used on client/from addresses have an MX RR accepting email.

Comment: Then you have to use `reject_unverified_sender`